# Android Studio Emulator errors and problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, device-emulation

I have a problem with runnind the android studio emulator.
I tried so many online solutions however, I didn't found any solution for the scenario I have.
The starting point is:
* Windows 7, 8gbRam, 64bit.
* A new installation of the android studio environment (IDE, SDKs etc...). 
* A simple project ("hello world")
* A device definition in the AVD manager.

Now, I'm running the device and waiting for it to launch.
I'm running the application on this device and the build is starting.
Then the device is crash.
Then I try to launch it again and after it is statring, it crash again and keep logging errors.
I'm restarting the Android Studio. 
Then in the AVD manager, I have a message that there is no emulator installed.
Then I press install and nothing is going on...
Another wiered thing is that the avd.exe has been deleted from the platform-tools in the android sdk folder.
This is happening all over again after uninstalling all the environment and installing it again (I mean removing everything, including the JVM, SDK, IDE...)
I did a screen recording of that...
https://youtu.be/9XVsQF7QufA

Please help me solv that... I didn't found a solution over a month...
Thanks.

Comment: You have Updates Pending in Event log, try with that first.

Comment: @Gotiasits I did that... it didn't change anything... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after some investigations and mind blowing...
I found what is deleting the adb.exe from my computer.
It was mrt.exe...
A Microsoft tool...
Tanks.